# Sever responding with a 500 error and error code 204 off and on, while development server works perfectly

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I have searched and searched to find an answer to this strange issue on Google App Engine (PHP). My application generates the error below, but only say once out of 5 or 6 calls. There is absolutely no error on the development server. I have disabled APC caching and have tried things like changing version numbers.

The error shows on the log as follows:

```
2014-05-14 11:53:30.270 /mapi/index.php?action=login&params%5Blogin%5D=kumar76&params%5Bpassword%5D=kumar123&_=Submit 500 121ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.75.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/537.75.14 module=default version=1-0-test

24.55.15.118 - - [14/May/2014:09:53:30 -0700] "GET /mapi/index.php?action=login&params%5Blogin%5D=kumar76&params%5Bpassword%5D=kumar123&_=Submit HTTP/1.1" 500 0 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.75.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/537.75.14" "simplycrowmapi.appspot.com" ms=121 cpu_ms=0 exit_code=204 app_engine_release=1.9.4 instance=00c61b117c1279e8c136be007edf2c17b5bfd1

W 2014-05-14 11:53:30.270 
A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit.
This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application.   
(Error code 204)
```

my php.ini:

```
google_app_engine.enable_functions = "php_sapi_name, gc_enabled, phpinfo"
allow_url_include = "1"
upload_max_filesize = 8M
apc.cache_by_default = "0"
apc.enabled = "0"
```

Comment: Do you mind to share the code for your mapi/index.php?

Comment: the index.php makes a bunch of calls:  <?php
$_componentsDir = 'components/';
require 'config.php';
require $_componentsDir.'DB_PDO.php';
require $_componentsDir.'SC_Application.php';
require $_componentsDir.'SC_Models.php';
require $_componentsDir.'SC_Messages.php';
require $_componentsDir.'GoogleMapsHelper.php';

$app = new SC_Application();


foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
    
 if(is_array($v)){
  foreach ($v as $k1 => $v1) {
      syslog(LOG_DEBUG,'->'.$k1.' => '.$v1);
  }
 } 
 else{
  syslog(LOG_DEBUG,$k.' => '.$v);
 }  
 
}

$app->start();
$app->processRequest();
$app->end();
?>

Comment: Can you try adding 'setting apc.cache_by_default = "0"' to your php.ini and see if that fixes the problem?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I already did that before I posted it. It did not help at all. I have added my php.ini above. Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 1):

I also got this error using CodeIgniter v2.1 and v3 on app engine and got this error as well.

It happens when using `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');`

Then after a few random page refreshes this error pops up.

After changing the following in `database.php`:

`'pconnect' => TRUE,`

into

`'pconnect' => FALSE,`

This errors is gone in my application.
Now both version 2.1 and 3 are working for me.

Maybe there is a similar setting in the framework or code you're using.

Comment: Thanks!!! This helped I removed "PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true" and the problem went away!

Comment: I tried setting pconnect to false (I'm using mysql) and it didn't help. I am still having issues getting my home/default controller working

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, also resolved by using non-persistent connections. According to App Engine's Cloud SQL documentation https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/#PHP_Managing_connections it can only serve 12 concurrent connections, which is probably less than the number of front-end PHP processes.

For PDO, that's

```
PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false
```